# Directive to change the element after the loss of focus in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

i can check whether i have focus on particular element or not by using

```
ng-focus="focus=true" ng-blur="focus=false"
```

but the thing is that i want to make custom directive such that it will change my element model after its focus is lost so i think i cant use `ng-focus` or `ng-blur`.
Ok let me tell you what exactly i want 
Suppose i have a textbox
and if users enter 10 and  `tab` so,After the lost of focus my textbox must return currrent month and year
For eg if user enter

```
10
```

Output should be `10/12/2016`

Thanku

Comment: does input field is a datepicker?

Comment: then you could use ng-change

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at ng-model-options with ng-change

http://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-model-options.asp

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions

Here's a basic plnkr which you could expand:
https://plnkr.co/edit/crkrhOic70dYjViuUh6x?p=preview

```
app.component('myComponent', {
  bindings: {
    obj: '<'
  },
  template: '<input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.someDate" ng-model-options="{updateOn: \'blur\'}" ng-change="$ctrl.change()"/>',
  controller: function MyComponentCtrlx() {

    this.change = ()=>{
      this.someDate += '/12/2016';
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Sir i think this will not help my diredctive must be an attribute something like this <input type="text" ng-model="inputdata" changeFocusadd> and my directive app.directive('changeFocusadd',{}) because suppose for some input i want to add this and another directive what should i do...?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-model` with `ng-blur` and a specific method (`changeDate()`) to return what you need when the focus is lost:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="textInput" ng-blur="changeDate()">
```

Controller:

```
$scope.changeDate = function () {
    $scope.textInput = $scope.textInput + '/12/2016';
}
```

Of course you should add a better way to calculate the date in `changeDate` I did something fast just to give you an idea.

EDIT: Sorry it was ng-blur when you lost focus

To use it as directive:

JS:

```
app.directive('myInput', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: 'true',
      scope: {
         inputdata: '='
      },
      template: '<input type="text" ng-model="inputdata" ng-blur="changeDate()">',
      controller: function ($scope) {
         $scope.changeDate = function () {
             $scope.inputdata = $scope.inputdata + '/12/2016';
         }
      }
  };
});
```

HTML:

```
<my-input inputdata="textInput"></my-input>
```

Comment: No i want  a custom directive which will be common to all controller

Comment: Edited to add directive.

Comment: Sit i think this will not help my diredctive must be an attribute something like this <input type="text" ng-model="inputdata"  changeFocusadd> and my directive app.directive('changeFocusadd',{}) because suppose for some input i want to add this and another directive what should i do...?